# @push('scripts') not working in version 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using laravel 5.4.I need use scripts through `@push` scripts, but it's not working.

Here is my code in index blade:

```
@push('scripts')
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-colorpicker/2.5.1/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js"></script>  
@endpush
```

In master layout:

```
some scripts.....
@stack('scripts')
```

When  I've used it like this,get works.

```
@push('scripts')
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-colorpicker/2.5.1/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js"></script>  
@endpushonce
```

When I use **@endpushonce** instead @endpush it's working.But why not with the **@endpush**

Comment: Hmm, never seen `push` before; I would think `@yield("scripts")`, `@section("scripts")[...]@endsection` would work here though, wouldn't it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply .I've tried it.It yields content properly,but it's not worked for scripts

Comment: I always include the script for `jQuery` before the `@yield`, making it loaded before any other scripts that require it, but I'm not sure what "not worked for scripts" means in your case.